# Azure Function error: "The Application could not be found"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Good afternoon,

I have developed an Azure Function but when running it in an Azure environment, I am getting the following error: {"error":{"message":"The application could not be found","code":"ApplicationNotFoundError","correlationId":"blabla-blabla-bla-blablablabla"}}

Here is my code:

```
[FunctionName("GetOperationData")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string id = req.Query["id"];

        var applicationInsightsAppId = "blablabla-blablaba-blabla-blablalbla";  
        var apiKey = "thisIsMySecret";  

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apiKey);

        var query = $@" requests
            | where id == '{id}'                 
            | join kind=inner (exceptions) on operation_Id
            | join kind=inner (dependencies) on operation_Id
            | join kind=inner (traces) on operation_Id
            | project id, name, url, success, resultCode, 
                      operation_Name, operation_Id, client_Type,
                      client_IP, client_City, client_StateOrProvince";


        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { query = query }),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{applicationInsightsAppId}/query"
            , content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult(responseString);
    }
```

And here is the error:

[image]
[image]

I checked all my configuration and seems that everithing it's ok, so my role is contributor.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

***I have used your code and got the expected result***

**`Code:`**

```
using  System;
using  System.IO;
using  System.Threading.Tasks;
using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using  Newtonsoft.Json;
using  System.Net.Http;
using  System.Text;
using  System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace  Company.Function
{
public  static  class  TestFunction01
{
[FunctionName("GetOperationData")]
public  static  async  Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route  =  null)] HttpRequest  req,
ILogger  log)
{
log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string  id  =  req.Query["id"];  

var  applicationInsightsAppId  =  "*********";
var  apiKey  =  "******************";  

HttpClient  client  =  new  HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apiKey); 

var  query  =  $@" requests
| where id == '{id}'                 
| join kind=inner (exceptions) on operation_Id
| join kind=inner (dependencies) on operation_Id
| join kind=inner (traces) on operation_Id
| project id, name, url, success, resultCode,
operation_Name, operation_Id, client_Type,
client_IP, client_City, client_StateOrProvince";

var  content  =  new  StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { query  =  query }),
Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var  response  =  await  client.PostAsync($"https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{applicationInsightsAppId}/query"
, content);

var  responseString  =  await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return  new  OkObjectResult(responseString);
}
}
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

When I change the value of `applicationInsightsAppId` to an incorrect one in the code, then I started getting the error.

[image]

Make sure, you are using correct `applicationInsightsAppId`, `apiKey` values.

Comment: Good day! Thank you! The ApiKey was not correct!